# Kotlin - Firebase Database - Convert DataSnapShot to Hashmap

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm retrieving a node from Database that looks like this:

```
 DataSnapshot { key = appointment, value = {timeAppointment=12:00pm, dateAppointment=12/12/1221, clientUID=Bu4sw8ouUUhDv0Ut1IKqeh8kESg2, caseManagerName=Karla Moreno, userName=Sakura Nakamura, formatAppointment=Zoom} }
```

This DataSnapshot is being stored in a custom callback.
However, I'm only able to retrieve it as a DataSnapshot. I'd like to retrieve the values, and display them using a TextView.

Is there a way to convert it into a HashMap, other than hardcoding the values into a HashMap?

Here is my code:

```
 class ViewAppointments : AppCompatActivity() {
 var readAppointment: String? = null

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_appointments)

     readData(object : AppointmentCallback {
         override fun onCallback(value: DataSnapshot) {
             //Here readAppointment is of type DataSnapshot
             readAppointment = value.toString()
             Log.d("ZXC", "$readAppointment")
         }
     })
     displayData()
 }

 private fun displayData() {
     // returns null
     Log.d("ZXC", "Display appointment from Database: $readAppointment")

 }

 private fun readData(appointmentCallback: AppointmentCallback) {
     val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
     val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

     val uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid)
     val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
         override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
             for (item in dataSnapshot.children) {
                 if (item.key.toString() == "appointment") {
                     //item = DataSnapshot { key = appointment, value = {timeAppointment=12:00pm, dateAppointment=12/12/1221,
                     // clientUID=Bu4sw8ouUUhDv0Ut1IKqeh8kESg2, caseManagerName=Karla Moreno, userName=Sakura Nakamura,
                     // formatAppointment=Zoom} }
                     Log.d("ZXC", "$item")
                     appointmentCallback.onCallback(item)
                 }
             }
         }
         override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
         }
     }
     uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
 }

 interface AppointmentCallback {
     fun onCallback(value: DataSnapshot)
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the map of values in a snapshot, call its [`getValue()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/ktx/package-summary#(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot).getValue()). This might actually be mapped to a `value` property in Kotlin.

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to mention that I'm storing the node into a custom callback. The node being the DataSnapshot I showed. It appears, I'm not able to retrieve any values from it, as I'm attempting to open it in another function. Although, I can see its keys, and values, I'm not able to retrieve them. Again, this is outside of ValueEventListener. I apologize if I'm communicating this insufficiently, I'm just beginning to solve this issue. @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: Instead of describing the code in a comment, edit your question to include the minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem. For more on how to do this, see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've gone ahead, and provided the code used to retrieve the node,and how I'm storing it in a custom callback. It's 60 lines of code, but I thought it necessary to show it. If you have time, please let me know if you have any ideas on how to store the node in a way that allows me to call the keys to retrieve the values (if not I can resort to hard coding the values into a HashMap, but I want to avoid that if I can.

Comment: Instead of calling `value.toString()`, you'll want to call `value.getValue()` as said in my answer. That will give you a map, which you can then get the values from.

Comment: You were certainly right, Frank! I apologize I had a difficult time understanding where to call .getValue()

I was able to solve the issue using it like this:

val appointment = item.getValue(Appointment::class.java)
appointmentCallback.onCallback(appointment)

Thank you so much for your help!